# Accessing uniform variables from a Cg shader in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, shaders, cg

I am trying to implement a simple PC program with OpenGL, using mandatorily Cg shaders (no Unity whatsoever).

I have found some tips on this page http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/10/05/cg-1/ and kept the **Cgprogram**, **Cgcontext** and **Cgprofile** types in my own project.

Problem is: How can you access uniform variables in the C++ code?
I have tried the **glGetUniformLocation** way, but that won't work because the first parameter must be the program's ID of **GLuint** type and I have **CGprogram** type.

I have already searched by myself (including the Nvidia Cg 'tutorial') but I can't seem to find both Cg and OpenGL discussed on a page without having to deal with Unity.

***edit:*** I can now access the variables, but in my case I'm trying to change a texture, and it doesn't bind.

Comment: You do know that Cg is not simply a compatibility layer for GLSL right? It has its entire own runtime API because it can compile code to ARB VP/FP, dozens of NV assembly languages and of course GLSL.

Comment: Yes I do, but I didn't manage to understand how it works, there's so little documentation about it, so if someone can help me with this I'd be so grateful.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Cg in about 12 years. I think the original "The Cg Tutorial" is available for free from NVidia these days though. That explains all of the basics even though it is about 12 years old. See [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_appendix_b.html) for more details. Unity did not even exist when that book was written, so I have no idea what you are talking about to be honest though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to find a way to access uniform texture variables.

First (after preparing the GL window) you have to initialize the Cg stuff:

```
myCgContext = cgCreateContext();
myCgVertexProfile = cgGLGetLatestProfile(CG_GL_VERTEX);
cgGLSetOptimalOptions(myCgVertexProfile);
myCgFragmentProfile = cgGLGetLatestProfile(CG_GL_FRAGMENT);
cgGLSetOptimalOptions(myCgFragmentProfile);

myCgVertexProgram =
    cgCreateProgramFromFile(myCgContext, CG_SOURCE,"../vertexshader.cg", myCgVertexProfile,"VS_Main",NULL);

myCgFragmentProgram =
    cgCreateProgramFromFile(myCgContext, CG_SOURCE,"../fragmentshader.cg", myCgFragmentProfile,"FS_Main",NULL);

cgGLLoadProgram(myCgVertexProgram);
cgGLLoadProgram(myCgFragmentProgram);
```

Then, in your *display* function, you have to do what you usually do, but put the following lines **exactly BEFORE** the actual draw (glDrawArrays in my case):

```
CGparameter loctex = cgGetNamedParameter(myCgFragmentProgram, "tex"); // in my fragment shader I have declared: "uniform sampler2D tex;"
cgGLSetTextureParameter(loctex, IDtex[1]); // IDtex is my array of texture IDs
cgGLEnableTextureParameter(loctex);
```

You can find more examples of accessing Cg variables in the NVIDIA OpenGL SDK projects (but that's difficult...); otherwise I have found great simple examples of using Cg with OpenGL here (scroll down & check right column):
http://perso.limsi.fr/jacquemi/RGA-TD/index.html

Comment: That resource looks pretty good. Do you still need more samples?

Answer (score 1):

`cgGetNamedParameter`

Example code:

```
CGprogram cgprog;
cgprog = cgCreateProgram(...);
cgGLLoadProgram(cgprog);
CGparameter modelviewproj, lightpos;
modelviewproj = cgGetNamedParameter(cgprog, "modelviewproj");
lightpos = cgGetNamedParameter(cgprog, "lightpos");
```

Sample code paraphrased from the book Advanced Game Development with Programmable Graphics Hardware by Watt Policarpo.

Comment: Note: I don't really know how Cg works. I just happen to have a book that uses it.

Comment: Thank you very much but texture still won't change. I wish I had access to more examples from this book to sort this out.

Comment: The book comes with a full C++/Cg rendering engine. Do you have an e-mail? Maybe I can send you some relevant pieces of code for handling textures.

Comment: Thank you very much. My e-mail is normally found on my profile. You can also find me on twitter @ety04.